# Do GC App Engine deployments of class B1 go idle, even if they have min of 1 instance?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-appengine-node

I have the following configuration in my app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs10
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
instance_class: B1
```

With this configuration, will my instance go idle even if it does not receive requests?

My node app is not really a https-server. It runs a couple of jobs based on data from a firestore db. I want this to always run and was wondering if this is possible with App Engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [App Engine Standard documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/how-instances-are-managed) the instances of a service with manual scaling won't be shutdown even if there isn't workload:

> **Manual scaling**
>
> Manual scaling specifies the number of instances that continuously run regardless of the load level. This allows tasks such as complex initializations and applications that rely on the state of the memory over time.

But notice that instances might be shutdown and restarted at some point due to maintenance tasks. I would suggest you to read that full doucmentation page to learn more about [how instances are managed](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/how-instances-are-managed) with the different scaling types.